# How can I update oldest data from duplicated values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have load number in to the tmp table and when check in the main table can see some have the duplicated.

My question is how can I update only 1 record from the duplicated values.

Eg.

```
Number       STATUS_ID
10000006       401
10000006       401
10000006       401
10000006       401
10000006       401
10000006       401
10000006       401
```

More over in the table i have around 500K record which have 60K record are duplicated with not the same number as in example how can I update it in the same time

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you tell the before update and after update data for the table for at least 2 distinct numbers?

Comment: Seems like an odd table design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowid`.  Something like this:

```
update t
    set col = . . .
    where rowid = (select min(rowid) from t where t.number = 10000006)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I have try this but when to update more than one number it still update only the last row

update t
set status_id = '0'
WHERE rowid in
(SELECT max(rowid)
FROM t
where Number in ('10000006','46565466'));

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
update t
set col = '....' --your update value here
where rowid = (select max(rowid) from tt where tt.number = t.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytics to get the max(rowid) for each Number value.

```
    update t 
    set status_id = '0' 
    WHERE rowid in 
    (SELECT max(rowid) over (partition by Number)
     FROM t 
     where Number in ('10000006','46565466')
     );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use row number:

```
UPDATE dupes
SET SOMECOLUMN = .......
FROM dupes
WHERE 
Number+'-'+STATUS_ID+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY STATUS_ID)) 
IN
SELECT KEY
FROM
(
SELECT
Number+'-'+STATUS_ID+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY STATUS_ID)) AS KEY
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY STATUS_ID) as seq
from dupes
)test
WHERE seq = 1
```

Comment: apologies SQL server head on, you need to switch out the + concatenation for ORACLE equivalent, CONCAT - I will update if you havent figured that out already.

Comment: If answers are marked down, can a reason be provided please